# How to send response back from service to client when an event in service is fired?

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, wsdl, rad-studio

I am using `embarcadero rad studio 2010` and programming language as `c++` and we are communicating with an external `.net dll` through `WCF Service`.

Communication is done by Importing `WSDL` in `embarcadero` and we are able to call service through `WSDL`.

Now I want to send a response back from service to client when an event is fired in the service. How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Callback functions in the WCF service. You will have to call the callback function in the host to send any data to the client at any time.

Please visit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-duplex-contract

Comment: I did the same thing in the following way.
https://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/721/push-data-wcf-callback-service

But it doesn't work for me because after that I was not able to host the service.

Comment: Do you mean your service stops responding? If so you should play with the service behaviour attributes. Set SyncronizationContext to false, ConcurrencyMode to multi. Otherwise, I see no reason why you can't host the service.

Comment: Hi Banis my service got hosted successfully.It was having error "Operations marked with IsOneWay=true must not declare output parameters, by-reference parameters or return values". It got fixed by removing return type from functions.
Now problem is how will i get notified in my c++ after importing wsdl or should i do something in my c++ application for notifications?

Comment: Callbacks are not supposed to return anything since they are one way. When you implement your interface in the client you would have to also implement the callback functions. When you call any of your callback functions in host, your callback function will be called immediately on your client. Your client must also inherit from the callback interface.
You can simply trigger an event within your client when a callback is called, then pass the values to the event handler which the handler will show the notifications you wanted.

Comment: Thanks @Bans, However my interface is not visible in WSDL for implementation.